# Adding PHP code to single template in 2023 edition of WordPress theme

Tags: themes, single

Im looking at [this tutorial](https://www.dreamhost.com/blog/guide-to-wp-custom-fields/).

But adding this code snippet to templates/single.html doesn't work.

```
<?php
$meta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'Sponsored Post' );
if( $meta[0] == 'Yes' ) {
?>
<p>This post is sponsored content, and we received a free copy of the product in order to conduct our review.</p>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That tutorial is for a classic PHP theme, but 2023 is a modern block theme, it works completely differently. You can't put PHP in the HTML files in `templates` folder. You should think of these files as starting content, not PHP files, and any changes you make in the side editor are saved in the database as posts of type `wp_template` and `wp_template_part` that override these files.

If you want to insert PHP into a block theme it needs to be done via a block. The easiest route is by writing a short code, then using a shortcode block to insert it into the theme.

---

As a sidenote, be wary of these types of tutorials. It's telling you to add a custom field to let you set a post as a sponsored post, which on the surface sounds reasonable. The problem comes when you need to exclude sponsored posts from the homepage, or show a list of sponsored posts in a sidebar. Now you're forced to write more code to make that happen, and because the data is in a custom field ( post meta ) the performance is awful.

Instead a custom taxonomy, something you can generate code for by filling out a form on a WP generator site, would give you a proper GUI in the editor for free, template files (`templates/taxonomy-name.html`, archive pages that can show up in google sitemaps, REST API endpoints for javascript etc. This and the performance in a worst case scenario could be 100x faster.

If you need to filter/search/group posts that do or do not have this field then it should be a custom taxonomy. Perhaps a `Post Features` taxonomy with `Sponsored`/`Featured` etc.

Likewise, a category or tag would do the job better than a custom field.

Comment: "custom taxonomy  category or tag would do the job better than a custom field" - do you have links to such tutorials ? Because most tutorials talk about custom fields mainly.

Comment: @anjanesh you ask an expert to point you to lesser experts :)

Comment: using custom fields for everything in WordPress is extremely popular because it's easy and super popular plugins like ACF only support post meta/custom fields for storage. A very quick google of custom taxonomy WordPress should yield hundreds if not thousands of tutorials. Likewise lots of people have asked how to create a custom taxonomy on this site, and if you want to know if a post does or not not have a tag/category/custom taxonomy term, that's also a single dedicated question you could ask that people have already asked and answered on the site

Comment: also not all tutorials are good, and can tell you to do bad things, read the official docs before blindly following tutorials

Comment: But most of the tutorials are for pre-modern block theme, right ? I guess modern block theme came when gutenberg  launched ?

Comment: block themes have been around for a few major versions, but my comment wasn't specifically about block themes but tutorials in general. Also a lot of things are still exactly the same, CPTs still work the same, shortcodes still work the same etc etc. You could switch to a classic style theme and continue the tutorial but what I suggested would still be a good thing to do